# How can I time maximum download times for images?

Tags: javascript, image

... for different browsers.

I want to do this purely in JavaScript by setting the src to an image and then timing how long it takes to error out.

I have an image which will take so long to load that they will error out.  I know these spots on the web via trial and error, so I can point the .src attribute to this image and see how long it takes an error to be thrown.

I know how to catch the error using:

```
window.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    }
}, true);
```

However I don't know the best way to time how long it takes the error to be thrown.

Comment: What would you want to do with this information anyway? It won’t necessarily be the same for the same browser on two different machines, since in some the user can configure this value. And if there’s a proxy in play. that might affect timeouts too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Date objects getTime function to get a start and end time, and then subtract start from end when the error occurs:

```
(function(){
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   var start =(new Date()).getTime();
   img.onerror = function(){
      var end = (new Date()).getTime();
      console.log("Took "+(end-start)+" milliseconds");
   };
   img.src = "http://someimageurl.com/someimage.jpg";
})();
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding a random `?rand=xxxx` (where `xxx` is randomly generated onto the end of the URL to make sure the browser's knowledge of it is never cached.

Comment: this is nice because I can run it in the console.  However, after running it in the console, the times varied a lot, not only across browser, but for each run.

Comment: @user3294399, well like jfriend00 says, use a cache buster method to make sure you dont get a near immediate error/success as the browser will cache the response of the url. Otherwise there is going to be some variance, as you have to take in account network speed, traffic congestion, etc

Comment: that would help normalize the readings, I normally just use a time stamp, it doesn't have to be random, it just has to vary uniquely ... I'll just use the start time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `console.time({String})` and `console.timeEnd({String})`:

```
console.time('some function');

someFunction();

console.timeEnd('some function');

// outputs ==> 7.624ms (or the like) in
// Chrome, and by default, the number is
// rounded in the Firefox console
```

You'll see a big difference from the first time the script is loaded to subsequent tests, since the browser caches JS.  Also, on my system, the times vary anywhere from 1 to 5 ms each test, so you'll have to do lots of runs and get the average.